# Reading file line by line and print line if the line contains any of the values in enum

Tags: java

```
So far I did is 

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project2 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      File file =new File("D:/log/logging.log");
      Scanner in = null;
      try {
          in = new Scanner(file);
          while(in.hasNext())
          {
              String line=in.nextLine();
                  if(line.contains(""))
                      System.out.println(line);
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

 } 
 public class Example(
    public enum Searchword {
        info,debug
    }}
```

I need to search if the line contains any one of the values of enum then need to print the line. Is it possible to search and how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by this line   if(line.contains("")) ?

Comment: You can use the `name()` method of the enum constant, for example `SearchWord.info.name()`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `java.nio` and Java 8 Streams - there is a declarative approach

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    enum Search { info, debug }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get("pathToFile");

        Files.lines(path)
             .filter(Main::containsSearchTerm)
             .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static boolean containsSearchTerm(String input) {
        return Stream.of(Search.values())
                     .map(Search::name)
                     .anyMatch(input::contains);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more complete answer with some aditional information:

The java compiler will add a few methods when it creates enums. One of these methods is the static .values()

This returns an array of all the enum values.

It also creates a member method .name() which returns a string representation of the enum.

Using these two methods you can loop over all the values in enum for every line and then when the line contains the enums string representation, print it.